# GitHub Copilot not making suggestions in VS Code

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, github-copilot

I'm in Ubuntu 22.04.

I installed the latest extension of Github Copilot, and updated VS Code to the latest version.

In the bottom right, I see the Copilot icon that toggles it. You can see in the picture below that when I click it, I get prompted to disable it. So it should be enabled already.

[image: Copilot icon]

This is my output in the View dropdown:

[image: output view]

> Not installing CopilotChat- Not VS Code Insiders

I have closed and re-opened VS Code. I have rebooted my machine. I've tried multiple languages (C++ and Python), tried opening different folders, and tried new vs. existing files.

I am signed into Github, and have my settings synced. You can see that in the image below.

[image: synced]

Why is this happening, and what should I do to resolve this?

Comment: related to the error message: https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2023/03/30/vscode-copilot#_getting-started-today if you want CopilotChat, you need to use VS Code Insiders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the issue. The settings.json file had disabled inline suggestions, despite having enabled them in the settings UI. I updated the line to be

`"editor.inlineSuggest.enabled": true,`

and that fixed it.